# Beautiful Soup Python click on tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<a data-iso-code="inr" data-symbol="₹" class="currency-select-button" 
href="#">₹ - INR </a>
```

How can I click on this tag, how to check 'data-iso-code = = "inr" '???
i have tried soup.find('a' , data-iso-code= 'inr') but it is giving error as:-

```
'SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression'
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup is a Python package for **parsing** HTML/XML.

Comment: yeah I know that I was parsing a website where I got stuck in this.... there are many 'a' tags so to differentiate I have to check data-iso-code but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Remember beautiful soup is not a web browser, but a parser: therefore the action of 'clicking' isn't quite the same: it doesn't execute a Javascript model in the way that a web browser does.

That said, it can be made to 'follow' links if you make a primitive spider-robot (make sure that if you do this, you look at your target sites `robots.txt` file.

Assuming you've got code which looks something like this to get a reference to the 'a' tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
mytag = soup.a # or use soup.findall('a') etc and loop over the results
```

then you can now look at the properties of that tag:

Note, you *can't* do `if 'data-iso-code' in mytag`: but you can do something like this:

```
def has_correct_attr(tag, attr, val):
    has_attr = False
    try:
        if mytag[attr] == val:
            has_attr = True
        else:
            has_attr = False
    except KeyError:
        has_attr = False
    return has_attr

has_correct_attr(mytag, "data-iso-code", "inr")
```

(code written in here, not tested so watch for typos)